# How to separate words from a sentence (only using character arrays and no built-in c++ functions)?

Tags: c++

I wrote this code to separate words from a sentence. I have to use character arrays(no strings) and can't use any built-in function(restricted by instructor). This does not work .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char sentence[100]={'\0'}, word[100]={'\0'};
  cin.getline(sentence,100);
  for(int i = 0; sentence[i] != 32 || sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)
  { 
    word[i]=sentence[i];
  }
  cout << word;
}
```

Comment: How does using a **single** `word` array answer your goal of separating a sentence into words???

Comment: Use paper and pencil and calculate what the following expression evaluates to: `sentence[i]!=32 || sentence[i]!='\0'` when `sentence[i]` is, say, for example, the letter 'A'. Once you do that, you will have the answer to your own question.

Comment: Correct indentation is always a plus. Also be clear about what you mean when you say "it does not work". Also whats 32?

Comment: I indented your code for you. See what a nice difference a few whitesapce characters can make for your eyes?

Comment: @barakmanos one word at a time.

Comment: But the loop runs only until the first space!!!

Comment: @Borgleader 32 is the ASCII code for space.

Comment: @barakmanos I am using this as a function.

Comment: @Zee, you can use it as whatever, it still will stop looping at the first space

Comment: @StoryTeller, thanks.

Comment: No you're not, you're doing it directly in `main`!!!

Comment: By the way, since you haven't specified **how** you want these words separated, you may as well print the sentence as is. It will display the words separated by spaces.

Comment: @StoryTeller it doesn't stop and I can't understand why. Moreover, I am passing an integer by reference which keeps the count of iterations.

Comment: −1, this is completely useless, it won't work with chinese.

Comment: @barakmanos in my real code.

Comment: @ybungalobill I didn't write it for Chinese !

Comment: @ybungalobill: If there's anything **not** to down-vote this question for is Chinese characters. The question specifically says character arrays (i.e. `char[]`). Chinese characters are wide (i.e., `wchar_t`, `short`, etc).

Comment: So what have you posted this code for??? If you want us to refer to "your real code", then post your real code, not something else.

Comment: @barakmanos: They are not, most of the world uses [utf-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/). Anyway, my point is that separating sentence into words based on whitespace is incorrect.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Whatever, that's not `char`.

Comment: @Zee: Please post your actual code, and please explain (as I have already noted to you in one of the comments above) how exactly you want to have these words separated (because at present, you may as well print the sentence as is, and the words will "come out separated").

Comment: @barakmanos: `utf-8` **is** `char` on lots of systems. I can pass Chinese into this code on any UNIX system.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Well, not on all systems, and half of the questions/answers on this website will not work for Chinese (specifically questions and answers about ASCII characters, specifically on systems which do not support Chinese "natively").

Comment: @Zee if its space than compare to `' '` instead of 32. Also AFAIK, the character encoding is not guaranteed/required to be ascii so this code would not be portable with that magic constant.

Comment: The loop will stop when it encounters a character that is equal to both 32 and 0. That's a long wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd like to separate all of the words in this sentence, so you can't make loop stop when it meet first blank.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char sentence[100]={'\0'}, word[100]={' '};
  cin.getline(sentence,100);
  for(int i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)
  { 
    word[i]=sentence[i];
  }
  cout << word;
}
```

Above code may can help you.